# Invalid argument on vagrant up, git

Tags: windows, git, vagrant

I try to run my Vagrant machine and I get this error:

> D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/posix.rb:116:in
>   run!': fatal: unable to access
>   'C:/Users/?╤В╨О╤П?╤П/.config/git/config': Invalid argument
>   (Librarian::Posix::CommandFailure)`

File even doesn't exist, when I create it, I get 'wrong configuration file' or something like this, even if the file is empty
Here is the full log. What can I do?
http://pastebin.com/xDh8zGHW

LOG:

```
D:\CPS\pgs>vagrant up Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty32' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: pgs_default_1452370788731_40960
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Installing Chef cookbooks with Librarian-Chef...
==> default: Auto-generating node name for Chef...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives... D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/posix.rb:116:in `run!': fatal: unable to access 'C:/Users/?╤В╨О╤П?╤П/.config/git/config': Invalid argument (Librarian::Posix::CommandFailure)
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git/repository.rb:138:in `block in run!'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git/repository.rb:147:in `logging_command'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git/repository.rb:137:in `run!'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git/repository.rb:60:in `fetch!'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git.rb:145:in `block in repository_update_once!'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/environment/runtime_cache.rb:72:in `block in once'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/environment/runtime_cache.rb:67:in `memo'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/environment/runtime_cache.rb:72:in `once'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/environment/runtime_cache.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in delegate_to_backing_cache'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git.rb:144:in `repository_update_once!'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/git.rb:91:in `cache!'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/local.rb:22:in `manifest_search_paths'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/source/local.rb:31:in `found_path'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:65:in `expect_manifest!'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:53:in `fetch_manifest_data'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:49:in `manifest_data'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/librarian/chef/source/local.rb:28:in `fetch_version'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:121:in `fetch_version!'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:113:in `fetched_version'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:59:in `version'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/manifest.rb:97:in `satisfies?'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/dependency.rb:121:in `satisfied_by?'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:103:in `block in check_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `each'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:104:in `check_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:63:in `block in recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block in recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block in recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block in recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:70:in `block in recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:187:in `block in scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:186:in `scope_checking_manifest'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:211:in `block in map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `each'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:210:in `map_find'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:152:in `block in resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:179:in `block in scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:178:in `scope_checking_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:164:in `block in scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:223:in `scope'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:163:in `scope_resolving_dependency'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:151:in `resolving_dependency_map_find_manifests'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:62:in `recursive_resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver/implementation.rb:50:in `resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/resolver.rb:23:in `resolve'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/librarian-0.1.2/lib/librarian/action/resolve.rb:26:in `run'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/vagrant-librarian-chef/action/librarian_chef.rb:52:in `resolve_and_install_cookbooks'
        from D:/vargant/gems/gems/vagrant-librarian-chef-nochef-0.2.0/lib/vagrant-librarian-chef/action/librarian_chef.rb:16:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:78:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/match_mac_address.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:74:in `import'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/import.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_clone_snapshot.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/prepare_clone.rb:15:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/customize.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:224:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:199:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:561:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:185:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:185:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```